# Como obtener valores de un fetch?

Tags: javascript

Soy nuevo en esto de promesas en js. Quiero hacer lo siguiente:

Tengo una variable `nomP`, hago mi petición con fetch a una api  lo cual me devuelve un json.

Lo que quiero es que un valor de ese `json` quede almacenado en `nomP` para usarlo afuera del fetch

```
let nomP;

fetch(enlace)
.then(resp => resp.json())
.then(data=> nomP=data.nombre)
.catch(e=>console.log(e))

console.log(nomP)
```

Comment: Cuál es el problema al almacenar el valor del json en una variable?

Comment: Hola Marcelo, bienvenido a SOes. Para lograr lo que estas buscando, de la forma que lo has planteado, deberías usar `await/async`

Answer (score 0):

`Fetch` es una función asíncrona, esto quiere decir que no cortará la ejecución del código mientras espera por la respuesta de la consulta.

Dado que el tiempo de respuesta de la consulta tarda más que la ejecución de las siguiente s lineas de código, `nomP` siempre será `undefined`, la forma correcta de trabajar esto es mediante `.then()` para controlar la respectiva respuesta y hacer algo, ya que del contrario, no hay forma de asegurar que realmente la petición al enlace se llevó a cabo.

En el siguiente código imprimo `nomP` inmediatamente y luego la imprimo con un retraso de 8 segundos para que se aprecie bien el fenómeno.

Puedes leer más de fetch [acá](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch)

```js
var nomP;
enlace = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
fetch(enlace)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => nomP = data)
console.log("Imprimiendo nomP inmediatamente", nomP)

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("Imprimiendo nomP luego de 8 segundos", nomP)
}, 8000);
```

Comment: muchas gracias ya entiendo pero no logro resolver mi problema subire el codigo completo

Comment: publique el codigo como otra respuesta la verdad soy bastante nuevo espero tu ayuda porfavor

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` es una funcion del navegador que funciona de forma asincrona al ser un wrapper de [XMLHTTPRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Esto tiene varias implicaciones, pero lo que aqui te esta sucediendo es que al ser asincrona, no bloquea el hilo principal de ejecucion de JS, por tanto, cuando quieres comprobar el valor de tu variable (que has asignado dentro del `then` de ese `fetch`) pueden pasar tres cosas:

- Que `fetch` sea mas lento que tu ejecucion de JS y por tanto ese valor no se ha asignado.
- Que `fetch` sea mas rapido que tu ejecucion de JS y por tanto podria dar el valor que esperas.
- Que `fetch` falle, y por tanto el valor, de nuevo, no se ha asignado.

Tienes varias formas de enfocar el problema en este caso.

- Usando la sintaxis de promesa te recomendaria hacer TODO lo que tengas que hacer como resultado de ese fetch dentro del `then`. Quedando un codigo asi:

```js
fetch = () => Promise.resolve({json: () => Promise.resolve({nombre: 'un nombre'})}) // Sobreescribo fetch para ilustrar el ejemplo. Esto NO SE DEBE HACER.

let nomP;

fetch('miUrl')
.then(resp => resp.json())
.then(data => {
  nomP=data.nombre
  console.log(nomP)
  })
.catch(e=>console.log(e))
```

Otra opcion es usar la sintaxis async/await, aunque si estas en el scope global no te lo recomendaria. Tu ejemplo quedaria asi:

```js
fetch = () => Promise.resolve({json: () => Promise.resolve({nombre: 'un nombre'})}) // Sobreescribo fetch para ilustrar el ejemplo. Esto NO SE DEBE HACER.

const main = async () => {
  const fetchResult = await fetch('miUrl').catch(e=>console.log(e));
  const response = await fetchResult.json().catch(e=>console.log(e))
  const nomP = response.nombre
  
  console.log(nomP);
};

main();
```

De esta forma, con async/await estas emulando lo que quieres hacer, `bloqueando` el hilo de ejecucion de la funcion donde esta incluido el `await`

Answer (score 0):

//Es lo que trato de hacer traer valores desde una api ponerlos a un JSON y poder devolver //el json para usarlo donde debo

```
        function armarJSON(res) {
        let data = [];
        let nomP;
        res.forEach(resp => {
          fetch(resp.proveedor).then(resp => resp.json())
          .then(datos=>{
            nomP=datos.nombre
          }) 

        data.push(
            {
                accion: `<button  class="btn btn- 
                warning"onclick="editarUnaLinea('${resp.url}')"><i class="fa fa-pencil 
                text-write"></i> </button> <button  class="btn btn- 
                danger"onclick="eliminar('${resp.url}')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>  
                </button>`,
                nombre: resp.nombre,
                detalle: resp.detalle,
                composicion: resp.composicion,
                ubicacion: resp.ubicacion,
                proveedor: nomP,
                categoria: resp.categoria
            }
        )
    });
    datoJSON = JSON.stringify(data);
}
```

Comment: Es una respuesta a tu pregunta?